# how to run a specific cell in a notebook from another notebook

Tags: programming, procedural-programming

I have a long `Mathematica` code in a notebook, denoted by NB1. Since it is a very long code, and I need only some of the outputs from NB1 to be used in another notebook denoted by NB2, I assigned `Cell Tags` to those NB1 cells generating the outputs required by NB2. I like to know how to recall the tagged cells in NB1 into NB2.

I know how to run NB1 while in NB2 but I do not want to run all the operations in NB1 as I only need a subset of the NB1 outputs.

Here is an example of NB1:

```
Clear[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]];
Clear[n, d, G, transfer, absorption, info, capParam, infoStock, 
edgeCapacityMat, infoStocks, system, reducedSystem, sa, wG];

SeedRandom[14];
n = 6;
d = 0.3;
G = RandomGraph[{Round[n], Round[n*(n - 1)*d]}, DirectedEdges->
True];

transfer = Table[t[i], {i, 1, n}]; (* transfer capacity *)
absorption = Table[a[i], {i, 1, n}]; (* absorption capacity *)
info = Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}]; (* information stock capacity *)

(* parametrization *)
capParam =Table[{t[i] -> RandomReal[], a[i]->RandomReal[]}, 
{i,  1,n}]//Flatten;
infoStock = 
Table[x[i] -> RandomInteger[{1, 10}], {i, 1, n}]//Flatten;

edgeCapacityMat[transferCap_, 
absorptionCap_] := (# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[
KroneckerProduct[transferCap, absorptionCap]];
infoStocks[stock_] := DiagonalMatrix[stock];
system = infoStocks[info].edgeCapacityMat[transfer, 
absorption];  (* fully defined system *)

reducedSystem = 
AdjacencyMatrix[G]*
system;  (* the system associated with AdjacencyGraph "G" *)
sa = SparseArray[reducedSystem];
wG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], 
EdgeWeight->sa["NonzeroValues"],DirectedEdges 
->True,VertexLabels -> "Name"];

(* @KGLR's answer: use this in formulating the "attention   
allocation problem in my paper  *)

ClearAll[edgeW];
edgeW = Module[{g = #, 
e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
   FindPath[##, \[Infinity], All]}, 
Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@
e}]]&;

desiredOutput1=edgeW[wG, 5, 2]
desiredOutput2=HighlightGraph[wG, edgeW[wG, 5, 2][[All, 1]]]
```

I like to use `desiredOutput1` and `desiredOutput2` in NB2, therefore I created two `cell tags` in NB1 to be recalled from NB2, but I do not know how to recall only the two cell tags from NB2.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NotebookEvaluate` with the `EvaluationElements` option. Here is an example:

```
ClearAll[x, y]; (* x and y are unassigned *)
nb = CreateDocument @ {
  ExpressionCell[
    Defer[
      x = 1;
      CreateDialog[{"X", DefaultButton[]}]],
      "Input", 
      CellTags -> {"a"}], (* we assign this cell tag 'a' *)
  ExpressionCell[
    Defer[
      y = 2;
      CreateDialog[{"Y", DefaultButton[]}]],
      "Input", 
      CellTags -> {"b"}] (* we assign this cell tag 'b' *)
};
(* now, run only tag 'a' *)
NotebookEvaluate[nb, EvaluationElements -> {"Tags" -> {"a"}}]
{x, y}
```

> {1, y}

Comment: Your answer works fine, however, I have already assigned `Tags` to each cell in my`Code` by using `Cell-Add/Remove` option, and I simply want to call those `Tags` into NB2. If I assign names for each calculation in NB1, I can simply retrieve them to NB2, no problem with that. But I do not want that. I like to retrieve an individual cell as a stand-alone element into NB2. I hope there is much less complicated version of your `Code` to bring all the cell tags into NB2.